NFS - mv command takes a long time
I have a program that at some point uses the mv command to move a pattern matching of files from one folder to another.
mkdir tmpdir
mv /path/to/files/pattern* tmpdir

The folders /path/to/files and tmpdir are both on an NFS share. It is mounted as follows in /etc/fstab:
192.168.10.10:/export/data /mnt/ml nfs auto,actimeo=1 0 0

The NFS share has the following in /etc/exports
/export/data 192.168.0.0/16(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)

The Problem
Some of these mv commands (as shown earlier) are taking upwards of hours (as indicated by timestamps before and after the move)
Here is a plot of number of files moved vs. the time it took to do so (in minutes).

Any idea as to what could be causing this? Or possible ways to diagnose what is causing this?

Mostly out of curiosity, 1) which NFS version? 2) are both folders on the same NFS mount? 3) are both folders on the same filesystem on the server? (in other words, are you 100% sure you aren't transferring them from the server to the local system and back? did you check that that's not the case?)


NFS Vers 4.2
Yes the /path/to/files is located in the NFS mount and so is the newly made tmpdir
Is this not the same as #2?

